# How to set port number of remote VPN server in Network Manager widget

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, client

I'm trying to set PPTP connection on Ubuntu's own network manager widget.

Whe I set the IP address of the server with port number *(Like, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port`)* and try to initiate vpn connection, I'm getting *VPN connection 'VPN connection 1' failed to connect: 'invalid gateway 'gateway''* error.

How can I set the port of the remote VPN server port number on network manager?

[image]

Comment: What's under "Advanced..."?

Comment: @Zacharee1 no separate port or address setting under Advanced tab. I did double check.

Comment: I googled this a little, and depending on the PPTP server, it might not be possible to change the port.  At least in `poptop` (the `pptpd` server on some distros), the port number is hard-coded and not able to be changed or defined without a source code recompile; with that in mind, it may be that clients were never configured to permit multiple ports.   (on ServerFault: ["change default PPTP TCP port"](http://serverfault.com/questions/345674/change-default-pptp-tcp-port), which asks for Debian, which Ubuntu is based off of)

Comment: @ThomasWard Actually I'm trying to setup for connection to *SonicWall* without *NetExtender Client* because of it's inabilities. I try to connect with PPTP because of NetExtender link looks like `ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol ` but the server is working on different port. If it is actually not a *PPTP* connection than what should I have to use?

Comment: @SencerH. I can't give guidance on NetExtender or SonicWall, but as the Network Manager has to utilize existing `pptp` client functions, it's limited by the underlying `pptp` client on Ubuntu and its related libraries, which seem to have the same limitation as `poptop` and doesn't permit port specification (which would explain the current situation).  That said, given PPTP is still ancient and extremely low on the security scale, I would suggest using a different VPN technology if possible.